# clang is giving 'undefined reference' error when nm is showing the item as defined

Tags: android, c++, clang

I'm using VS 2019 v16.11.5 to compile and test an Android app.
All these libraries built and ran before I upgraded to 16.11.
I had to go back and do some minor modifications and cannot get them to rebuild.
One example is shown here.

I'm building a .so file and linking 5 *.a files and one *.so file.
All six libraries have been completely rebuilt successfully.
Library Dependencies are:
Support_Droid;Services_Droid;BaseLib_Droid;Common_Droid;_Linux;Interfaces_dynDroid;$(StlLibraryName)

The linker gives me:

```
undefined reference to 'Dictionary::get_string_translation(wchar_t*, wchar_t*, int, wchar_t const*)'    
undefined reference to 'attrVarIndex::getArrayPointer(itemBase*&)'
undefined reference to 'attrVarIndex::hCattrVarIndex(int, unsigned long)'
```

Running *nm -C -g -u --defined-only libServices_Droid.a*   gives

```
00000088 T attrVarIndex::getArrayPointer(itemBase*&)  
00000000 W attrVarIndex::destroy()  
00000000 T attrVarIndex::attrVarIndex(int, unsigned long)  
00000000 T attrVarIndex::attrVarIndex(int, unsigned long)  
000000f8 T attrVarIndex::~attrVarIndex()
```

Running *nm -C -g -u --defined-only libSupport_Droid.a*   gives

```
00003f1c T Dictionary::get_string_translation(char*, char*, int)  
0000421c T Dictionary::get_string_translation(wchar_t const*, wchar_t*, int, wchar_t const*)  
0000400a T Dictionary::get_string_translation(wchar_t*, wchar_t*, int)  
000041d2 T Dictionary::get_string_translation(wchar_t*, wchar_t*, int, wchar_t const*)
```

Setting ‘Enable Verbose Output’ to Yes in the Linker Options shows (in a bunch of tries):

```
Src\ARM\Debug/libSupport_Droid.a succeeded  
Src\ARM\Debug/libServices_Droid.a succeeded  
Src\ARM\Debug/libBaseLib_Droid.a succeeded  
Src\ARM\Debug/libCommon_Droid.a succeeded   
Src\ARM\Debug/lib_Linux.a succeeded 
Src\ARM\Debug/libInterfaces_dynDroid.so succeeded   
C:\\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs\armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so succeeded 
C:\\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs\armeabi-v7a/libc++abi.a succeeded
```

in that order.

How is clang missing these few definitions out of the hundreds involved in this link?
How can I trace the problem?

Comment: please show the full error message, I'm guessing a library order problem, `libSupport_Droid.a` needs to be listed after the libraries that use it

Comment: Alan Birtles - are you saying that the definition must be defined AFTER the usage of the function? I always thought it was the other way around, the definition must be linked BEFORE the usage.

Comment: Yes the linker goes through each library in turn collecting undefined symbols any unused symbols are discarded, the undefined symbols are then looked up in subsequent libraries

Comment: Alan - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/24675715#24675715

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this in the future: Alan is correct, clang expects the definition to be in or after item's declaration module.